# Codeigniter return 0 result when I use Union All in query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$sql = 'SELECT bind_id, Title, category, image_url, keyword, style_Binder_id, end_user_id, NULL AS cphoto_id, NULL AS cphoto, NULL AS title, NULL AS company_id, DATE FROM styleBinds  
UNION ALL  
SELECT NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , keyword, style_Binder_id, end_user_id, cphoto_id, cphoto, title, company_id, date_time FROM company_photo  
ORDER BY DATE ASC';
$sql =$this->db->query($query);
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    $result=$sql->result();
    return $result;
}else{
    echo "0 records";
}
```

When I run this query in phpmyadmin it return 150 results

but In codeignitor It returns 0 results...

Comment: Hmm wierd deleted my post so other people have some space to hopefully post the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo problem. You have reversed the argument and the assignment.
code should be

```
$query=$this->db->query($sql);

if($query->num_rows() > 0){
  return $query->result();
}else{
  return NULL; //controller should decide what to do with no model results
}
```

Comment: Still same problem @DFriend

Comment: Found a syntax problem with `if($query->num_rows > 0){` it should be `if($query->num_rows() > 0){` I have edited my answer with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :Assuming that you have date_time filed in your table and I suggest to use `isnull` instead of `null`.

```
SELECT bind_id, Title, category, image_url, keyword, style_Binder_id, end_user_id, NULL AS cphoto_id, NULL AS cphoto, NULL AS title, NULL AS company_id,date_time FROM styleBinds 
UNION ALL  
SELECT NULL as bind_id , NULL as Title , NULL as category , NULL as image_url,keyword, style_Binder_id, end_user_id, cphoto_id, cphoto, title, company_id, date_time FROM company_photo  
ORDER BY date_time ASC;
```